# Local Server throws 403 after reinstalling KDE Desktop and SDDM

Tags: apache2, kde, virtualhost

Systeminfos:

```
Ubuntu 22.04
KDE-Plasma-Version: 5.24.6
KDE-Frameworks-Version: 5.92.0
Qt-Version: 5.15.3
Kernel-Version: 5.15.0-10048-tuxedo (64-bit)
```

During a system cleanup, I seem to have uninstalled something that caused the following error to occur after a reboot.

```
The current theme cannot be loaded due to the errors below, please select another theme.
file///usr/share/sddm/breeze/main.qml: No such file or directory
```

In the terminal I then executed the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm-theme-breeze
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
sudo apt install --reinstall kde-plasma-desktop
sudo apt install --reinstall kde-standard

sudo systemctl unmask packagekit.service
sudo systemctl start packagekit.service
sudo systemctl unmask mysql.service
sudo systemctl unmask apache2.service

but mysql did not worked so i had to reinstall it
sudo apt-get --purge mysql*
sudo apt install --reinstall mysql
sudo apt install mysql-server

sudo chmod o+x $HOME
```

After that the login and the KDE desktop worked again.

However, I now have a problem with the local web server.
When I call a local page I get a 500 error in the browser.

Checking the apache2 error.log gives me this message

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 8214] [client 127.0.0.1:41014] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/user/_projects/
```

Now I can't figure out how to fix the problem.

Comment: i have update my post adding Systeminfos

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Remixes such as that provided by Tuxedo are not official Ubuntu*